# How to clear all fields when user change material after adding an item?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to clear all the fields when the user changes Material. I will share code with you. This material changed causes an issues such as value not defined.

```
// on material changed //
    materialChanged(event: { component: SelectSearchableComponent, value: any }) {
        //material selected
        console.log('event: ', event);
        if (event) {
          this.temporaryUnit = event.value.unit.value;
        }



 // additem function //

        addItem() {
          const found = this.ListOfUsedMaterials.find(item =>
            item.goodId == this.selectedGood.id && item.device == this.deviceTypId);
          if (found) {
            found.quantity += Number(this.item.quantity);
            this.item.quantity = "";
            this.selectedGood = "";
          } else {
            this.ListOfUsedMaterials.push({
              title: this.selectedGood.value,
              quantity: Number(this.item.quantity),
              goodId: this.selectedGood.id,
              unit: this.selectedGood.unit,
              device: this.deviceTypId,
              manufacturer: this.deviceManufacturerId,
              mark: this.deviceMark
            });
            this.onClear(event);
          }
        }
```

Comment: Could you pls share you the code from your template where you call `materialChanged`.

Comment: @NorbertBartko : here's a code for example: http://dpaste.com/06ZX13W

Answer (score 1):

Pls use `(change)="materialChanged()"` in you template.

Also you to way binding `selectGood` so why don't use it?

```
materialChanged() {
   console.log(this.selectedGood);
}
```

> This package has been deprecated

Also its recomendet to use `ionic-selectable` insted of `select-searchable`.
See [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-select-searchable).

Comment: I do but: _This material changed causes an issues such as value not defined._. This should solve your _value not defined_ issue.   
If there is something elso wrong with your code i cant help you, unless you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com).